# Jquery Dynamic Select In Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have tabs on a page that I want to turn into a select box when viewed on a phone. I'm using Bootstrap so showing and hiding the tabs and select box is not a problem. My problem is I can't figure out how to get the paths into the select box. I'm not pulling anything from the database and most of the examples I found online where how to create a select from records in the db.

Here is the relevant **View** code:

```
<div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
  <div class="page-nav-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Everything", activities_path, class: "#{'active' unless params[:content]}" %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Posts Only", activities_path(content: "posts"), class: "#{'active' if params[:content] == 'posts'}" %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container visible-xs">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <select id="dynamic_select" class="form-control">
            <option value="<%= link_to activities_path %>">View Everything</option>
            <option value="<%= link_to activities_path(content: 'posts') %>">View Posts Only</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The dynamic select works if I just put in Google or Stack Overflow URL's in the values so I know the jQuery is there and working. How can I get Rails to put the correct paths in the values?

Thanks.

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper `link_to` creates an actual `a` element, which you don't want inside your `select` options. You should be able to just do this, assuming your JavaScript is working:

```
<select id="dynamic_select" class="form-control">
  <option value="<%= activities_url %>">View Everything</option>
  <option value="<%= activities_url(content: 'posts') %>">View Posts Only</option>
</select>
```

The path and URL helpers simply output a string. Depending on how your JavaScript works, you may want either one, but I'm guessing it's expecting the full URL.

Comment: Drenmi, Thanks. That only inserts the part of the URL after the slash. How do I get the fully qualified URL?

Comment: I updated the answer. Just replace `path` with `url` like so: `activities_url`.